# Using Razor.Engine.NetCore in rest api solution .net core 3.1 with Url.Encode

Tags: razor, .net-core

I'm trying to use Razor.Engine outside of MVC, everything works good, but now I need to encode url inside Razor template.

My template is:

```
<html>
<p><span><a href="@Model.BaseUrl?data=@Model.UrlParams">Click here</a></span></p>
</html>
```

My Model is:

```
BaseUrl = "http://mysiteurl",
UrlParams = "{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;43869906-dfdb-435c-a570-c4578d859e78&quot;}"
```

I need to encode the UrlParams so I tried

```
href="@Model.BaseUrl?data=@Url.Encode(@Model.UrlParams)"
```

But no luck :(

Is it possible to encode url inside Razor template? and how?
I could not find the ability to add namespaces

I Also tried with RazorEngineService.create(config).RunCompile(...) but still not working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with this

```
@Model.BaseUrl?data=@System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(@Model.UrlParams.ToString())
```

and it's working :)